# How to make static variable of object A immutable to state changes on object B

Tags: java, variables, static, scope, immutability

If I have some simple class such as. The problem is instance B of this class can impact instace A's `j`.

```
public class Tester {
    private static int j;

    public Tester() {
    }

    public void setJ(int i){
        this.j = i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }
}
```

In my real world application, `j` needs to be `static` (so `private static` classes can use it). However I encounter a problem when I make it `static` which is in the above example. If we create two separate instances of this class I can show the problem:

```
Tester testOne = new Tester();
Tester testTwo = new Tester();

testOne.setJ(1);
testTwo.setJ(2);

System.out.println(testOne.getJ()); //returns 2
```

then by setting the static variable in `testTwo`, it overwrites what I previously set as for the static variable in `testOne`. If I was to remove `static` then `j` would be immutable with respect to `testTwo.setJ(2)`, but I can't have this.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Well, yes.  This is what `static` does.

Answer (score 0):

if a variable is made static then if you change once then it will be reflected everywhere
When you are doing `testOne.setJ(1);` the variable is set to 1 but again you are calling `testTwo.setJ(2);` so again the variable is set to 2,so finally you are getting 2

*In my real world application, j needs to be static (so private static classes can use it).* 
you can create an object then call the instance variable without making it static

Answer (score 0):

Static fields will be common to all instances of the Class. In your case, since `j` is static, its common to any number of instances you create for the class. That's change made by 1 instance will be reflected in the other.

See it like this.

```
There is a static `j` - since its static, it'll be initialized to 0 by default.
j = 0  // initially

testOne.setJ(1) // This makes j = 1
j = 1 // Now

testTwo.setJ(2) // This makes j = 2, since j is shared by all instances of your class(property of static fields)
j = 2 // Finally
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a bug, it's correct behavior. If you really need smtg like you've just explained, you may try such way:

```
public class Tester {
    private static int j;
    private boolean jWasSet;

    public Tester() {
    }

    public void setJ(int i){
        if (!jWasSet) {
            this.j = i;
            jWasSet = true;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if you want to set it again?!

Comment: from this point of author: "it overwrites what I previously set as for the static variable in testOne", I understood that he doesn't want it be changed after first setting =)